# Connect to remote repository and fetch data

Tags: c++, c, git, libgit2

I want to connect to the remote repository and fetch data from him. I include and use the libgit2 library. This my code:

```
const char* url = "http://address.to.repository";
git_libgit2_init();

git_repository* repo = nullptr;
git_remote* newremote = nullptr;
git_buf* buf;
git_strarray remotes = {0};


if (git_repository_init(&repo, "/tmp/gittest", false) != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_repository_init, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}

if (git_remote_create_anonymous(&newremote, repo, url) != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_remote_create_anonymous, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}


if (git_remote_connect(newremote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_remote_connect, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}

if (git_remote_connected(newremote) != 1)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_remote_connected, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}

git_remote_add_fetch(repo, "origin", "refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master");


if (git_remote_lookup(&newremote, repo, "origin") != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_remote_lookup, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}

if (git_remote_fetch(newremote, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_remote_fetch, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}

git_remote_free(newremote);
git_repository_free(repo);
git_libgit2_shutdown();
```

I'm not sure, that I did all correctly. And now, I have three errors:

```
problem with git_remote_connect, error message : 'authentication required but no callback set'
problem with git_remote_connected, error message : 'authentication required but no callback set'
problem with git_remote_lookup, error message : 'remote 'origin' does not exist'
problem with git_remote_fetch, error message : 'authentication required but no callback set'
```

I don't understand, how to connect to the remote repository correctly and fix these issues. So, I will be grateful if you give advice or share links on how to fix these issues.

**UPDATE**

I have read the documentation and looked at the topics, which discuss the different problems with libgit2. I have created a function which can solve my issues (maybe :))

```
int cred_acquire_cb(git_cred** out,
                    const char* url,
                    const char* username_from_url,
                    unsigned int allowed_types,
                    void* payload)
{
    return git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new(out, "user", "pass");
}
```

In the main code, I write:

```
git_remote_callbacks callback = GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_INIT;
callback.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;
```

On the internet, I found some examples for old library version. And now I can't understand how to use this callback option in `git_remote_connect` function.

**UPDATE2**

I tried to go another way and made this:

```
git_strarray remotes = {0};
git_cred* cred = nullptr;
git_proxy_options opt = GIT_PROXY_OPTIONS_INIT;

if (git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new(&cred, "user", "pass") != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}

if (git_remote_connect(newremote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, git_cred_acquire_cb(&cred, url, "username@bitbucket.org", 1, nullptr), opt, remotes) != 0)
{
    const git_error *lastError = giterr_last();
    std::cerr << "problem with git_remote_connect, error message : '" << lastError->message <<"'"<< std::endl;
}
```

But compiler tells me the next errors:

```
error: expression list treated as compound expression in functional cast [-fpermissive]
     if (git_remote_connect(newremote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, git_cred_acquire_cb(&cred, url, "ableigdev@bitbucket.org", 1, nullptr), opt, remotes) != 0)

error: cannot convert ‘git_cred_acquire_cb {aka int (*)(git_cred**, const char*, const char*, unsigned int, void*)}’ to ‘const git_remote_callbacks*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int git_remote_connect(git_remote*, git_direction, const git_remote_callbacks*, const git_proxy_options*, const git_strarray*)’
     if (git_remote_connect(newremote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, git_cred_acquire_cb(&cred, url, "ableigdev@bitbucket.org", 1, nullptr), opt, remotes) != 0)
```

How to fix it? And which one of two way more correct?

Comment: Just pointing out that you're doing strange things in your initial example : "anonymous" remotes are in-memory only, they are never created in the repository. So your creation/connect will always fail, because there's no configured URL. Your `git_remote_add_fetch` is targeting the existing git remote (it might be creating it in the process), but then you're loading it again and fetching this one, so your initial anonymous remote is never used (and might actually always fail to perform anything, as it has no URL configured).

Comment: @tiennou If I create an anonymous remote repository I can't connect and fetch data from him? Or I wrong understand you?

Comment: Please ignore what I just said ;-). You're setting the URL when creating the remote, I glossed over that when reading the docs. That only leaves the point that you're actually stomping over "origin"'s URL and fetching from that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote you're connecting to is asking yourself to authenticate. You need to use the `callbacks` parameter of `git_remote_connect` to pass a `git_cred_acquire_cb` (docs for the [struct](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/type/git_remote_callbacks), for the [callback](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/callback/git_cred_acquire_cb)).

This will get called when authentication is requested, along with the "type" of authentication you need to provide. See the [cred](https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/cred) section of the docs for the details (which supports password or SSH methods), and which are used to build a `git_cred` object that your callback should return.

Here's a minimal example (compilation errors intended) :

```
int my_git_cred_cb(git_cred **cred, const char *url, const char *username_from_url, unsigned int allowed_types, void *payload)
{
    if ((allowed_type & GIT_CREDTYPE_USERPASS_PLAINTEXT) != 0) {
        return git_cred_userpass_plaintext_new(&cred, "user", "pass");
    } else {
        /* Some other kind of authentication was requested */
        return -1;
    }

    return 1; /* unable to provide authentication data */
}

void perform_fetch(git_remote *remote)
{
    git_fetch_options opts = GIT_FETCH_OPTIONS_INIT;

    opts.callbacks.credentials = my_git_cred_cb;
    opts.callbacks.payload = NULL; /* you'll get that pointer back as the payload parameter */

    return git_remote_fetch(remote, NULL, &opts, NULL);
}
```

Note that you don't need to go through all the steps (ie, connect, check connection), calling `git_remote_fetch` will cause the connection to be made and if it succeeded, the fetch will happen.

Comment: I have updated my topic. Please, look up. Maybe you have some advice.

Comment: Your example work is great! Now me interesting how to get from fetch data commit message, ssh, and author? Which function must I use?

Comment: Also, be interesting how to get name remote branches? I tried to use `git_branch_remote_name`, but I don't understand what does it mean the third parameter `canonical_branch_name` in this function.

Comment: Now that your fetch is ok, this means the commits from the remote are in your repository, so standard repository functions should be used (eg. git_revwalk will allow you to list commits, which will have the message & author). I do not understand what you're referring to with "ssh", as it's only the underlying transport your remote is/could be using, and doesn't functionally matter, so look at its URL.

Comment: For `git_branch_remote_name`, it seems the 3rd parameter must be a reference name, and it will return its branch short name. To clarify, `"refs/remotes/origin/master"` returns `"master"`, and I'd wager `"refs/remotes/origin/fix/404-error"" would return `"fix/404-error"`.

Comment: How to get the list all remote branch? I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: That's `git_branch_iterator_new`. To clarify, branches don't exist (yeah that's scary ), they're more like a "git porcelain" concept. At a lower-level they're just a file in some specific folder of `.git/refs` (like `refs/heads/` contains local branches, `refs/remotes/origin/` contains the remote branches of `origin`, etc.). That's why sometimes you can end up searching for a `git_branch` function while there's actually a generic version around `git_reference`.

Comment: I used `git_branch_iterator_new` and got the iterator. Next, I used `git_branch_next` and got git_reference. And finally, I used `git_branch_name` and got a branch name. But I got the second branch name. What function can I use to get the `git_reference` from the `git_branch_iterator`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You're getting a `git_reference` from `git_branch_next` already (you should be calling it in a loop until it returns `GIT_EITEROVER` BTW), and `git_branch_iterator_new` gives you all remote branch available. If you're trying to filter for a specific remote, you need `git_branch_remote_name`.

Comment: I have two remote branches: master and develop. The `git_branch_iterator_new` function gives me all remote branches, but not their names. In order to get names these branches, I can use the `git_branch_name` function. This function has one parameter. The type this parameter is `git_reference*`. How to get `git_reference` from `git_branch_iterator`?

Comment: Now, I use the next steps: `git_branch_iterator` (I got all branches) -> `git_branch_name` (I got git_reference, but the current branch is the second branch: develop) -> `git_branch_name` (I got name the second branch). Which steps must I do in order to get a name the first branch (master)? 
P.S. I hope, you will understand me. :)

Comment: The problem with `git_branch_iterator` is not actual. She was resolved. :)

Comment: I have a question about `git_revwalk`. I have got `git_revwalk` which I have got from `git_revwalk_new`. How to get commit's message and commit's author from `git_revwalk`?

Comment: I'd really like that you'd 1) accept the answer to your original question, on the basis that it resolved your authentication issue 2) give a close look to the existing documentation/headers, because it's (IMHO) pretty good 3) ask questions as actual questions instead of more comments on an "unrelated" question. Hint: look at the log example : https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/log.html

Comment: @tiennou what would be example parameters for my_git_cred_cb? I am confused with this example

Comment: @KS7X `my_git_cred_cb` is a callback called by the library when a remote requests authentication (ie. password, ssh keypair, etc.). You're supposed to check `allowed_types` so that you know which kind of credentials the remote expects (see the `git_cred_*_new` functions). HTH !